# Determine whether the given series converges or not

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Consider the series $\sum_{1} ^{\infty} a_n$ where
>   $a_n= \frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is square and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ otherwise.

How to figure out whether the given series is convergent or not ?

This series is a combination of two series one of which is convergent and the other one is divergent, so I think the whole series should diverge, but i am not sure.

What if $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ if n is odd and $a_n=-\frac{1}{n}$ if n is even?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the partial sum
$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\ .$$
Any $N$ can be "enclosed" between two squares, say
$$M^2\le N<(M+1)^2$$
and we then have
$$\eqalign{S_N
  &=a_1+a_4+\cdots+a_{M^2}+\langle\hbox{all other terms up to $a_N$}\rangle\cr
  &=1+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{M^2}+\langle\hbox{all other terms up to $a_N$}\rangle\cr
  &\le1+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{M^2}+1+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{N^2}\cr
  &<2C\ ,\cr}$$
where
$$C=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6\ .$$
Thus the terms $S_N$ are bounded above; they are clearly increasing since each $a_n$ is positive; and therefore the series is convergent.

In fact, since we have a convergent series of positive terms we can rearrange them at will and evaluate the sum:
$$\eqalign{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots
  &=(a_1+a_4+\cdots)+(a_2+a_3+a_5+\cdots)\cr
  &=\Bigl(1+\frac14+\cdots\Bigr)+\Bigl(\frac14+\frac19+\frac1{25}+\cdots\Bigr)\cr
  &=\Bigl(1+\frac14+\cdots\Bigr)+\Bigl(1+\frac14+\frac19+\frac1{16}+\cdots\Bigr)\cr
  &\qquad{}-\Bigr(1+\frac1{16}+\frac1{81}+\cdots\Bigr)\cr
  &=\frac{\pi^2}6+\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{\pi^4}{90}\cr
  &=\frac{\pi^2}3-\frac{\pi^4}{90}\ .\cr}$$

Comment: How you are getting pi^4/90 ?

Comment: @blueboy It's the known value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^4}$.  There are various ways to prove it, none of them particularly easy.

Answer (score 1):

The series with the square criterion converges because the terms $\dfrac1n$ follow the sequence of perfect squares and are sparse. In fact, you are summing $\dfrac1{k^2}$.

The series with the parity criterion diverges because the terms $-\dfrac1n$ are dense (you have an Harmonic series), and they are not compensated by the odd terms, which are known to form a convergent series.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to prove that certain subsequence are sparse or dense ?

Comment: @blueboy: write $n=f(k)$ where $k$ is dense.